# sass mixin is not working

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to compile the following SCSS code

```
//SCSS Code
@mixin box-shadow($shadows) {
   -moz-box-shadow: $shadows;
   -webkit-box-shadow: $shadows;
   box-shadow: $shadows;
}

.shadows {
   @include box-shadow(0px 4px 5px #666);
}
```

But the compiled CSS is not showing the vendor prefix attributes. I am using [SassMeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/) to compile this code.

```
//Compiled CSS
.shadows {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px #666;
}
```

Comment: it is compiling with all provided vendor prefixes.

Comment: It's working, check here: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/842a1565611a46f75cf51f77208f0957

Comment: No, it is not working for me http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/e9e5f8c8a04d4debdc1ed909fdbea2a9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It "doesn't work" because you have turned on the `autoprefixer` option (`options - autoprefixer`). Turn if off and you'll see the prefixed styles.

Note: [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) add those prefixes for you automatically. And also, as @rrd pointed, prefixes for [`box-shadow`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) are not needed nowadays.

Comment: Note to OP: don't manage vendor prefixes manually. use autoprefixer.

Answer (score 0):

You will find [Hugo Giraudel's article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/mixin-prefix-properties/) useful I think. That way you can ensure you get the vendor prefixes you want. On another note though, I don't think you need the box-shadow vendor-specific prefixes nowadays.